# How to prevent pushing SNAPSHOT version in maven-release-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project with lots of modules (and modules inside modules). I am using **maven-release-plugin** for controlling the versions in the **pom.xml** files.

When running command `mvn release:prepare` plugin is pushing two commits with messages: **"[maven-release-plugin] prepare release v0.9.0.38"** and **"[maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration"** accordingly. Herein the second one is just snapshot version.

Here is the **maven-release-plugin** settings:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <checkModificationExcludes>
                    <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>*/pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                </checkModificationExcludes>
                <branchBase>master</branchBase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When pushing I am setting the tag to the remote git project as well (You can see it in `<tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>`) so I need to push commits definitely, but I don't want it to push snapshot versions (e.g. 0.9.0.38-SNAPSHOT).

**Edit:**

### The problem:

As I am incrementing minor version of the project on each commit by running
`mvn release:prepare`.
e.g. Commits looks like following:

> [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
>   [maven-release-plugin] prepare release v0.9.0.38
>   (refactor) Code cleaned up
>   [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
>   [maven-release-plugin] prepare release v0.9.0.37
>   (feature) Added I18N support

This looks very ugly, and pushing three commits on every change is very bad solution only for just incrementing minor version of the pom file not manually.

### What do I need?

- Before every commit increment project version (including all modules)
- And set the tag to the remote git repository.
- And it should be done by one commit with custom message

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Even if you find a way to do it, your solution would not be conventional and so straight understandable by your peers. If it is not for an excellent reason, you should not change the core working of Maven release plugin.

Comment: What is exactly the problem with that? It is a change in your pom files which should be committed and of course in cases of git pushed...?

Comment: Update versions of the pom.xml to the new release one. Push it to the git repository, and set the tag too. Push only one commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Described behavior is intended - plugin increments version of your modules after releasing them which is normal. So the main advice is think twice before customizing it.

If you're using Git, you can set [pushChanges](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#pushChanges) to `false` to avoid pushing. After that you can rollback last commit and push changes

```
git reset HEAD~ --hard
git push origin master
```

Advice would be more practical if you explained why you consider the second commit as redundant.

Also you always can use [dryRun](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#dryRun) switch if you're not sure about changes.

**Update:**

1. Do your changes
2. `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<version-to-set> -DgenerateBackupPoms=false`
3. `git commit -m "your-comment"`
4. `git tag <your-tag>`
5. Push commit/tag

These steps can be easily aggregated to script file to avoid monkey-job.

As an alternative, you can look to [BuildNumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/), which also can be useful.

Comment: @Fonnadema, describe properly what do you want to achieve? Do you just need release and avoid version changing? Or you're using it inside some build automation like Bamboo or something.

Comment: I edited my question, and wrote what I need to achieve. Please review new edition.

Answer (score 1):

To just update versions you can use `release:update-versions` and then commit manually.

The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) also lists the `suppressCommitBeforeTag` option for `release:prepare`, which sounds like it should prevent committing.

Comment: `release:update-versions` just updates snapshot versions. `suppressCommitBeforeTag` caused an error: **Cannot perform a remote tag or branch without committing the working copy first**.

Comment: I think the error might be caused because "remoteTagging" is enabled. It needs to be disabled for `suppressCommitBeforeTag` to work. But are you sure that update-versions only updates snapshot versions? I'm quite sure I've used it to update any versions in the past. Documentation says it the version update as used by `prepare`, just without committing anything

Comment: Yes, "remoteTagging" is enabled, that's why I have edited my question.